# How do I get the Phone number on an account with C#?

Tags: c#, twilio, phone-number

I am trying to access the phone number on an account in C# with:

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);    
var account = twilio.GetAccount();
```

But I can seem to find the Phone Numbers on the account in there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any details will be really helpfull. What is GetAccount method doing? how do you want to get phone number?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

To get the phone numbers of an account you use the ListIncomingPhoneNumbers method:

```
var result = twilio.ListIncomingPhoneNumbers();
var numbers = result.IncomingPhoneNumbers;
```

There a number of different overloads for this method, depending on what you need to do.

Hope that helps.